# Javascript - Rock Paper Sissor Game error

Tags: javascript

So I just started to learn Javascript and I'm making a new game. I have made a code however, I get "Syntax error". I looked around and found different ways of doing it, however that is not going to help me learn. I was wondering if someone can tell me what logic is wrong with the code.

```
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or sissors?");

    var computerChoice = Math.random(0, 1);

    if (computerChoice =< 0.33){
        console.log("rock");
    }
    else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice =< 0.66) {
        console.log("paper");
    }
    else {
        console.log("sissors");
    }
```

Comment: The console usually tells you exactly where the syntax error is when you click on it.

Comment: `=<` should probably be `<=`. look into the browser's console for any issues.

Comment: It's also possible that you're missing some space between 0.33 and 0.34, so your game will be extra-enriched in scissors picks, ready to be exploited by serious connoisseurs of the game. :) And you misspelled scissors.

Comment: Also take note that `console.log()` doesn't work on browsers without a console. Just use `log()`

Comment: Gerald: I'm using Codeacademy and it doesn't do that.
Karthikr: Thank you for the help :)
Chris: Yea I changed the spelling :P
Marlo: I'm using Codeacademy and they want me to use console.log();

Comment: @NimitDesai I updated your code for fun. Try it if you want to learn some new things. It's on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/aj73k5jr/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `=<`, Javascript uses `<=`

You should use a Dreamweaver or something similar. It will help you a lot by telling you syntax error when you are typing code.

Comment: Suggesting that a new javascript developer acquire Dreamweaver for this purpose seems a little crazy, IMO.

Comment: Yeah probably.. But that's how I started and now I can't regret :)

Comment: Thanks Nathan :) Worked perfectly.

Comment: A good ide is always needed, but there are many out there that dont cost money.